# Anyone having problems with Greasemonkey @includes not firing?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey-4

I write Greasemonkey scripts to do all sorts of automation and screen scraping for my job. I've got a list of items/accounts to work on and I iterated through them pulling data from various web tools.

I trap the document ready event and start my processing from there, and when I'm done I'll load the next page in sequence either with a `window.href` or just clicking a link to the next page.

Every now and then when the page loads Greasemonkey doesn't run. There's no errors in the consoles and if I just refresh the page it works. It's like the `@include` directives are failing. I'd say the URL was changing but it's not, and a page refresh starts the script just fine (albeit with me having to stop what I'm doing and hit F5).

Anyone seen this before? Is there anything I can do about it (short of switching to Selenium)?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     testG
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var mySearches = localStorage.getItem('mySearches');
var myResults = localStorage.getItem('myResults');

if (mySearches){ 
     mySearches = JSON.parse(mySearches);


}else{
    mySearches = ["one", "two", "three","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39"];
  localStorage.setItem('mySearches', JSON.stringify(mySearches));
}

if (myResults){
   myResults = JSON.parse(myResults);   
}else{
   myResults = [];
}

$(document).ready( function() {

  var search = $("input[title='Search']");

  console.log("mySearches is " + JSON.stringify(mySearches));

  var mySearch = mySearches.shift();
    myResults.push(mySearch);
    localStorage.setItem('myResults', JSON.stringify(myResults));

  search.val( mySearch );

  if ( mySearches.length < 1){      
        localStorage.removeItem('mySearches');
    alert (myResults);
    }else{

        myResults.push(mySearch);
        localStorage.setItem('mySearches', JSON.stringify(mySearches));

        window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
    }

} );//END DOCUMENT READY
```

Comment: (1) If you "trap the document ready event" you most likely have a race condition -- triply so if the script isn't set for document-start. (2) Don't use Greasemonkey 4+, it's all kinds of fubar.  Use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey instead. (3) **Post code, especially a [mcve].**

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay, had to bang something together and it's been crazy the last few days. Added an example above. If I let this run long enough (figure a few hundred records in the "mySearches" array) it'll just stop at some point.